# Remove export Formats in devexpress Document Viewer tool in the Send Via Email Function

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Hi im currently looking for a solution for my problem im currently using devexpress usercontrol document viewer. i just notice that when i tried to send the report into my email it has too many formats which is i dont like. i need to hide it Please see this image

[image]

i want to remove a certain format on that list

this question is similar to my other question the difference is that this formats is located in this control and the other is in the export

i though if i remove the format in the export it will also remove the formats when sending the report in the email any suggestions? this is my code for removing formats in the export which is not reflecting in the send email function

```
  documentViewer1.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(new PrintingSystemCommand[] { 
PrintingSystemCommand.ExportRtf, PrintingSystemCommand.ExportTxt, PrintingSystemCommand.ExportMht, 
PrintingSystemCommand.ExportXls, PrintingSystemCommand.ExportXlsx, PrintingSystemCommand.ExportXps,
 PrintingSystemCommand.ExportCsv }, CommandVisibility.None);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PrintingSystemCommand.SendXls` and `PrintingSystemCommand.SendXlsx`:

```
documentViewer1.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(new PrintingSystemCommand[] { PrintingSystemCommand.SendXls, PrintingSystemCommand.SendXlsx }, CommandVisibility.None);
```

Take a look at [`PrintingSystemCommand`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingPrintingSystemCommandEnumtopic) enumeration for available values.